Poem About Misshapen Tree
Looking for a poem about a tree that has grown in adverse conditions, but is more interesting because it has more character. Thought it was written by a famous American poet but my searches don't seem to find anything. It is not a poem about good timber, but I encountered it in a forestry company office. It was a short poem less than 30 lines. Wind, snow, cold or something similar has made the tree's growth difficult.

Are you sure it's not "Good Timber" by Douglas Malloch? These two stanzas in particular seem like they're saying the same kind of thing that you're remembering:

The tree that never had to fight
For sun and sky and air and light,
But stood out in the open plain
And always got its share of rain,
Never became a forest king
But lived and died a scrubby thing.


Good timber does not grow with ease:
The stronger wind, the stronger trees;
The further sky, the greater length;
The more the storm, the more the strength.
By sun and cold, by rain and snow,
In trees and men good timbers grow.

My only doubt is that you say "It is not a poem about good timber" - do you mean that you already checked and it's not the specific poem entitled "Good Timber"?

Yes I checked a number of them before I asked the question

The Lightning Tree, perhaps? It's a song, but somewhat matches the theme of your question. A tree was struck by lightning, but continues to grow despite adversity. (And we should follow the tree's example)

Sorry definitely not this song.
